# Identify And Open Programs From Task Bar With Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am kinda new into Python and recently I made a  program that automatically fills my code and username in a game but the game's launcher icon gets moved around and the program doesn't work that good. Is there any way I can automatically find the position of the icon and click on it? Here is the code(It's bad):

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as KeyboardController
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MouseController
import time

keyboard = KeyboardController()
mouse = MouseController()
choice=0
Run = True

while Run :

    choice= input("What account do you want?(1,2,3): ")

    if choice == "1":
        time.sleep(0.5)
        mouse.position = (567, 1060)#cords of where launcher has to be to work#
        mouse.press(Button.left)
        mouse.release(Button.left)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        mouse.position = (544,470)
        mouse.press(Button.left)
        mouse.release(Button.left)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        keyboard.type('USERNAME')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        keyboard.press(Key.tab)
        keyboard.release(Key.tab)
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.type('password')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        Run = False

    if choice == "2":
        time.sleep(0.5)
        mouse.position = (567, 1060)#cords of where launcher has to be to work#
        mouse.press(Button.left)
        mouse.release(Button.left)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        mouse.position = (544,470)
        mouse.press(Button.left)
        mouse.release(Button.left)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        keyboard.type('USERNAME')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        keyboard.press(Key.tab)
        keyboard.release(Key.tab)
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.type('password')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        Run = False
        
    if choice == "3":
        time.sleep(0.5)
        mouse.position = (567, 1060)#cords of where launcher has to be to work#
        mouse.press(Button.left)
        mouse.release(Button.left)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        mouse.position = (544,470)
        mouse.press(Button.left)
        mouse.release(Button.left)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        keyboard.type('USERNAME')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        keyboard.press(Key.tab)
        keyboard.release(Key.tab)
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.type('password')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        Run = False

    elif choice != "1" and choice != "2" and choice != "3":
        print("Invalid answer")
```

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use pyautogui' s screenshot function and then try to find where your icon is in the picture.

```
import pyautogui
import PIL
import numpy as np
img=PIL.Image.open("mygameicon.png")
screen=pyautogui.screenshot()
def find_loc(img,screen):
    img=np.asarray(img)
    screen=np.asarray(screen)
    img_size_y=img.shape[0]
    img_size_x=img.shape[1]
    for y1 in range(screen.shape[0]):
        for x1 in range(screen.shape[1]):
            if (screen[y1:y1+img_size_y,x1:x1+img_size_x] == img).all():
                return (x1,y1,x1+img_size_x,y1+img_size_y)

loc=find_loc(img,screen)
...
```

I don't know for sure but I think you could use opencv template matching instead to account for small errors in the pictures. Also you should use a lossless format like png instead of jpeg as the pixel values might change.